# How to find α in this Reduction Identity

Tags: trigonometry

In the reduction identity :

> *m* sin *θ* + *n* cos *θ* = √(*m²* + *n²*) sin(*θ* + *α*)

I am having trouble with determining the value of α.  Here is an example.

```
Problem : -7 sin θ - 24 cos θ
m = -7
n = -24
Using the above formula :
√(-7² + -24²) sin(θ + α) = 25 sin(θ + α)
```

From here, I use the following identities to attempt to determine α

> sin α = n / √(*m²* + *n²*)
>
> cos α = m / √(*m²* + *n²*)

```
sin α = -24/25, α = -74°
cos α = -7/25, α = 106°
```

At this point, I have two possible values for α.  My textbook states, "α is the smallest possible positive value that satisfies both of these conditions," and lists the value of α as 254°.   I'm a bit confused.  How did they arrive to that conclusion, and what steps can I take to solve the problem?

Comment: Where did a and b come from, are those supposed to be m and n?

Comment: Hint: see this page .http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384479/solve-the-trig-equation-cos-theta-%E2%88%92-sin-theta-1/1384530#1384530

Comment: $${\color{Red}{a sinx+ b cos x= \frac{|a|}{a} \sqrt{a^2+b^2}sin (x+\alpha)\\tan \alpha=\frac{b}{a}} }$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation $\sin\alpha=-24/25$ is satisfied not only by $\alpha=-74^\circ$ (plus multiples of $360^\circ$); there's another family of solutions, namely $\alpha=180^\circ+74^\circ$ (plus multiples of $360^\circ$). (Think about where on the unit circle you can get a sine of $-24/25$; there will be two places, equally distant from $-90^\circ$.)

Similarly there's a second family of solutions to the equation $\cos\alpha=-7/25$, namely $\alpha=-106^\circ$ (plus multiples of $360^\circ$.) (The two places where you can get a cosine of $-7/25$ will be equally distant from $180^\circ$.)

Putting these together you'll find $\alpha=254^\circ$ is the smallest positive $\alpha$ that meets the requirements.